# Playing a video and recording at the same time react-native(iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to play a video using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) and at the same time record the voice of a user using [react-native-audio-toolkit](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit).

The problem is if the video is playing and i start recording, the video stop and when i click play again it simply doesn't work. Once i stop the recording everything is back to normal i can play pause and everything work.

I'm not super fluent with iOS, but in any case would it be possible that's those two libraries can both use the same iOS functions and cause interference ? The problem would be in the Recorder of react-native-audio-toolkit, because playing a sound with it's player and playing a video with rn video at the same time works.

If so does anyone would know how to solve that problem ? Thanks in advance